# PHP code stop normal loading of site

Tags: php, str-replace, htmlspecialchars

I have this code to get the HTML source of a website/file and replace some parts of its content. Later I print the modified result

```
<?php
// Get a file into an array.  In this example we'll go through HTTP to get
// the HTML source of a URL.
$lines = file($link);

// Loop through our array, show HTML source as HTML source; and line numbers too.
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {

}
?>
<?php
$old = array("document.write(", "'", ")", "&lt;a href=&quot;", "&lt;/a&gt;", "target=&quot;_blank&quot;"); 
 $new = array("", "", "", "", "", "");
 $original = htmlspecialchars($line);
 $changed = str_replace($old, $new, $original);

?>
```

This code is in a file, I include this code using `<?php include('newfile.php'); ?>`

For some reason any other file after I include that file will not work, like `<?php include('somefile.php'); ?>` or `<?php get_footer(); ?>`

Any help will be appreciated
Sorry for my English

Daniel

---

I got this: Notice: Undefined variable: do_not_duplicate in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/135377/webspace/httpdocs/folder/wp-content/themes/one/index.php on line 47 Warning: in_array(): Wrong datatype for second argument in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/135377/webspace/httpdocs/folder/wp-content/themes/one/index.php on line 47

The error message has nothing to do with the code provided before, the error message has someting to do with Wordpress, on line 47 is this code: `<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue; ?><li class="contentli">`

---

**Update 1**

Error message says:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/135377/webspace/.../newfile.php(26) : eval()'d code on line 1

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/135377/webspace/.../newfile.php(30) : eval()'d code on line 1

Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/135377/webspace/.../newfile.php on line 32

---

**Update 2**

There is no error message but the content of the footer (`<?php get_footer(); ?>`) is on the source code of the site but not visible to users. (If I check the source code of the site i can find all the elements of the footer file, but these elements aren't properly rendered on the browser)

Comment: Do you get any sort of error message?

Comment: Your script most likely contains a fatal error and makes PHP stop. Enable error reporting, read the error message which will also say where and what your error is, fix the error then and everything should work as coded.

Comment: try setting error_reporting, so you see the error messages using:
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: 1. Are you sure that you're actually getting something here: `$lines = file($link);` 2. Are your error reporting levels set to maximum? 3. What does the server error logs say?

Answer (score 0):

Your not doing anything in you're loop... perhaps code should be:

```
<?php
// Get a file into an array.  In this example we'll go through HTTP to get
// the HTML source of a URL.
$lines = file($link);

// Loop through our array, show HTML source as HTML source; and line numbers too.
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    $old = array("document.write(", "'", ")", "&lt;a href=&quot;", "&lt;/a&gt;", "target=&quot;_blank&quot;"); 
    $new = array("", "", "", "", "", "");
    $original = htmlspecialchars($line);
    $changed = str_replace($old, $new, $original);

} 
?>
```

Comment: That's definitely a problem with the code but would it break anything? Maybe it would generate warnings....

Comment: Indeed, it should - depends on error settings - someone has pointed out that bit to him.

Comment: warnings shouldn't stop anything. They should display the error text but continue executing. I can imagine a warning because of the blank `$line` in `htmlspecialchars` and the corresponding empty string in `str_replace` but that's a guess...

Answer (score 0):

You are using a file function.please declare a link variable. for reference, please check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: I got this: Notice: Undefined variable: do_not_duplicate in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/135377/webspace/httpdocs/folder/wp-content/themes/one/index.php on line 47 Warning: in_array(): Wrong datatype for second argument in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/135377/webspace/httpdocs/folder/wp-content/themes/one/index.php on line 47

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with the code provided before, the error message has someting to do with Wordpress, on line 47 is this code: `<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
 if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue; ?><li class="contentli">`

Answer (score 0):

It's highly likely that you've got an error but you don't know about it. So let's try to get some more info. Consider the following for the top of the file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(~0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// Get a file into an array.  In this example we'll go through HTTP to get
// the HTML source of a URL.
```

continue with the rest of the file as-is. This will enable reporting all errors and displaying them. Hope this helps.

If you get any errors, please add them to your question.

Comment: I got this: Notice: Undefined variable: do_not_duplicate in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/135377/webspace/httpdocs/folder/wp-content/themes/one/index.php on line 47 Warning: in_array(): Wrong datatype for second argument in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/135377/webspace/httpdocs/folder/wp-content/themes/one/index.php on line 47

Comment: Check that line 47 for undefined variables and try to understand why those are undefined. It's most often a sign that variables have not been initialized properly. Initialize them as needed and these two notices should go away.

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with the code provided before, the error message has someting to do with Wordpress, on line 47 is this code: `<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue; ?><li class="contentli">`

Comment: @Daniel: If I run your `newfile.php` code, I get these errors: `Notice: Undefined variable: link in newfile.php on line 5

Call Stack:
    0.0001     629224   1. {main}() newfile.php:0


Warning: file(): Filename cannot be empty in newfile.php on line 5

Call Stack:
    0.0001     629224   1. {main}() newfile.php:0
    0.0033     629728   2. file() newfile.php:5


Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in newfile.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined variable: line in newfile.php on line 15
`

Comment: That means ???? I don't get it, at the moment if I do a `<?php echo $link ?>` the link is there.

Comment: @Daniel: Well this only means that the code you've given in question is incomplete and as you already found out, not the cause of error. How should anybody here give you any further hint then? I can't look into code I don't have nor execute it on a server I don't have. You might miss what this forum is able to do with your question.

Comment: I just fix the Wordpress error but now I don't get any error message. Things like `<?php get_footer(); ?>` still not working. 
Error message now says:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/135377/webspace/.../newfile.php(26) : eval()'d code on line 1

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/135377/webspace/.../newfile.php(30) : eval()'d code on line 1

Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/135377/webspace/.../newfile.php on line 32

Comment: Finally we found the fatal error I suspected in the first place. I think that's actually a step ahead. Fix especially the syntax errors, they most likely show that you mixed something. Try to prevent usage of eval (that only makes things hard to deal with and is extremely dangerous) and the fatal error is the actual blocker.